# breakline in textbf in multicolumns

Tags: line-breaking, multicolumn, adjmulticol

I have given a thesis template and I am trying to fill inside cover page, but whatever I do, the "thesis title" part don't break the line automatically. Here is the given code:

```
\newpage

\newgeometry{top=5.3cm, left=2.2cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{INSIDE COVER}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{THESIS TITLE: xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[3.5cm]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{MEMBERS OF THESIS STEERING COMMITTEE:}} \\[0.8cm]

\textbf{Thesis Advisor}  & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Assoc. Prof. Dr. A. John Doe}  \\
 & & \textbf{XYZ University} \\[0.8cm]

\textbf{Member}  & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Assoc. Prof. Dr. Jane Doe}  \\
 & & \textbf{XYZ University} \\[0.8cm]

 \textbf{Member}  & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Assoc. Prof. Dr. Bill Smith}  \\
 & & \textbf{XYZ University} \\[0.8cm]

\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\restoregeometry
```

If anyone help about the breaking the line? Thanks in advance.

P.S: For privacy, I edited names, etc.

Comment: a table `l` cell is single line always, you could use a `p` cell but simpler would be to take the title out of the tabular and make it a paragraph of its own

Comment: I changed `l` to `p` and it returned error: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <template> \endtemplate`

Comment: see any latex tutorial, p columns require a width `p{3cm}` or whatever but as I say I would just move the text before the tabular